# My 2010 VW Jetta Tdi won’t start - very low coolant and check engine light on & off

Tags: vw

My 2010 Jetta has been having some issues. Sometimes it’s hard to start- will take 2-3 tries before it starts up. Is this because it’s a diesel and needs to be primed before actually starting it up? The other day I had to jump it and it started just fine. I had battery/ alternator/ starter checked at auto zone and they said those are good. But 3 codes did come up when check engine light was on ( goes on and off). 
Now car is stuck at boyfriend’s work. He says he turned the car on and it started at first then the coolant light came on and when he tried to turn it back on he couldn’t.

Comment: It might be helpful to know what codes are being reported.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. Not quite sure where you are going with this question.  --Are you sharing frustration? (we feel your pain..) --Are you hoping to fix this yourself, perhaps as a learning exercise to understand more about how your car works?  --Are you just trying to understand what's wrong so you can communicate helpfully with your dealer or repair mechanic?  As stated, there is a lot we don't know about your vehicle. We really need more information about the car (check engine stored codes )